# Go to a record from a portal

Tags: filemaker, records, portal

I'm making an app for authors using Filemaker. I posted this question on their forum but still haven't gotten an answer.

My app is basically a place where people can keep track of all the details that go into creating characters and locations. In each book (record) I have a tab control with 4 tabs: Book Details, Character List, Location List and Group List. Within the character list tab I have a portal which shows a list of the characters for that book.

I'm trying to create a button for each row in the portal which takes me to that records details page (the one with the red box around it). Right now, it's set to go to the character details layout. However, whichever row I click on, it takes me to the last visited record. Is there a way to go to each row's record from the portal? If not, do you know of a way to do the same thing through another method? I have a list layout which I used before, however, it doesn't hide the records for different books. For example, if I select book 1, it still shows characters for book 2. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a button, attach a script or single command that uses the Go To Related Record script step using the same relationship as the portal.

Make sure the button fits within the row.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried that before, but for some reason it refused to work. Either way, thank you for your help! Enjoy the rest of your night!

Comment: You’re welcome and thanks. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hey, I tried implementing that on the location list but I ran into a snag. I have a field called location type which is a dropdown box. So, if you choose towns and cities, it will take you to that layout but if you choose Castles and Keeps it will take you to that page. I changed the button to do what you said, and I found the layout by calculation part but I can't figure out how to have it go to the records proper layout. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You have to go to a layout that is based on the same table occurrence that the portal is based on.